# Multiple DNS BIND servers (zones) for same domain

Tags: dns, bind, vps, master

I wonder if it is possible to have one domain, handled by 2 DNS servers, master zones.

For example, I have the domain, `example.com` on a registrar and I want to make `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`. I want to have `ns1.example.com` on VPS1 and `ns2.example.com` on VPS2, both having a BIND installed, pointing to VPS3, where the website is hosted.

Can be done, like that? To have 2 master zones for same domain, with one NS each, on different IP's, both  pointing to another one.

Answer (score 5):

This is a standard approach for setting up DNS.  Two DNS servers would be considered the minimum.

Usually you would nominate one as the master of the zone, and one as the slave.

The master config would look something like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        allow-transfer { <slave IP>; };
        file "/etc/bind/pri/db.domain";

};
```

And the slave would look something like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
       type slave;
       masters { <master ip>;};
        file "/etc/bind/sec/db.domain";

};
```

The slave will take updates from the master, so you only need to update the zone on the master and it will get copied to the slave.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I will try to do that between several vps as dns backups.